# Selenium Find xpath for suggestions from the dropdownlist

Tags: selenium, xpath

Guys could you please help me.

I need to find xpath for the iphone 6s (suggestion is given when i type 'iphone' in the searchfield)

[image]

This does not work:

```
Actions actions = new Actions (driver);
actions.moveToElement(searchField).perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("iphone 6s")).click();
```

Comment: The link text is not "iphone 6s" try the full text or use the data-query attribute?

Comment: How about `By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'iphone 6s')]"` ?

Comment: I tried it. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute following:

```
Actions actions = new Actions (driver);
WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
actions.moveToElement(inputField).sendKeys("iphone 6s")
.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[span[text()=' 6s']]")))
.click()
.build()
.perform();
```

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[span[text()=' 6s']]"}

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `"a[data-query='iphone 6s']"` should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-query='iphone 6s']")).click();
```

Comment: does not work. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[data-query='iphone 6s']"}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a waiter for the suggestions to appear and you can't use `By.linkText` since the results are not `<a>` tags.

Here is working example (Java) for the website:

```java
By searchInput = By.cssSelector("#gh-search-input");
By suggestionIPhone = By.cssSelector("ul.suggestion-list li[title='iphone 6s']");

driver.findElement(searchInput).sendKeys("iphone 6s");

new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(suggestionIPhone))
  .click();
```